# dynamic ng-click to be used in jquery rendered html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Using a great jquery plugin to handle a calender. All works well. (The white box is the button ng-click)

[image]

The plugin receives **data** from php(laravel) in the form of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var agendaEventData = {'10-17-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(gjxljlytnbwb)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(wtdlklytnbwb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'10-21-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(lcmdglytnbcc)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytnbcc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'10-24-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(224686908)">More detail</button></span>'},],'10-28-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(lcmdglytnblc)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytnblc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'10-31-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(gjxljlytnbpc)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(wtdlklytnbpc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'11-04-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(lcmdglytpbgb)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytpbgb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'11-07-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(gjxljlytpbkb)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(wtdlklytpbkb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'11-11-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(lcmdglytpbpb)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytpbpb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'11-14-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(gjxljlytpbsb)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(wtdlklytpbsb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'11-18-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(lcmdglytpbxb)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytpbxb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'11-21-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(gjxljlytpbcc)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(wtdlklytpbcc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'11-22-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(grzrklytpbdc)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(mrzrklytpbdc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'11-25-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(lcmdglytpbhc)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytpbhc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'11-28-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(gjxljlytpblc)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(wtdlklytpblc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'11-29-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(grzrklytpbmc)">More detail</button></span>'},{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(mrzrklytpbmc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'12-02-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytqbdb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'12-05-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(gjxljlytqbhb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'12-09-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytqbmb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'12-12-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(gjxljlytqbqb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'12-16-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytqbvb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'12-19-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(gjxljlytqbzb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'12-23-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytqbfc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'12-26-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(gjxljlytqbjc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'12-30-2015' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlytqbnc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'01-06-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvcbjb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'01-13-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvcbrb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'01-20-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvcbbc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'01-27-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvcbkc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'02-03-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvdbfb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'02-10-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvdbnb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'02-17-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvdbwb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'02-24-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvdbgc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'03-02-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvfbdb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'03-09-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvfbmb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'03-16-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvfbvb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'03-23-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvfbfc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'03-30-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvfbnc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'04-06-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvgbjb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'04-13-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvgbrb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'04-20-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvgbbc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'04-27-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvgbkc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'05-04-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvhbgb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'05-11-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvhbpb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'05-18-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvhbxb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'05-25-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvhbhc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'06-01-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvjbcb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'06-08-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvjblb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'06-15-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvjbtb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'06-22-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvjbdc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'06-29-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvjbmc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'07-06-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvkbjb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'07-13-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvkbrb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'07-20-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvkbbc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'07-27-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvkbkc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'08-03-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvlbfb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'08-10-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvlbnb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'08-17-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvlbwb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'08-24-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvlbgc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'08-31-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvlbpc)">More detail</button></span>'},],'09-07-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvmbkb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'09-14-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvmbsb)">More detail</button></span>'},],'09-21-2016' : [{content : '<span class="fc-event-action"><button ng-click="toggleModal(dxczhlyvmbcc)">More detail</button></span>'},],};</script>
```

Which opens a modal, which works fine with plain vanilla angular/html `<button ng-click="toggleModal('dxczhlyvmbcc')">More detail</button>` , however here is the problem. ng-click needs to be compiled to work, so i know that i need to use a directive, however as **i am new to angularjs**, my thinking might not be correct, is to get json from the data source but i am unsure who to give the data too as i am **confused with both jquery and angular are competing for priority.**

I am looking for an overview from someone as to what is happening in the javascript? Then i can proceed with the directive that compiles the ng-click to be used in the jquery calendar if that is the **best approach?**

Note i have read every stackoverflow article i could find on this topic.

Comment: It's tough to understand what your asking, but have you tried onclick instead of ng-click?  If your dynamic javascript is being created after angular does all its magic loading stuff, then ng-click could be ignored and unnecessary.  That all being said, dynamic code is often a difficult path to go down.

Comment: What jQuery plugin is it? If placed in directive where you have angular scope access can probably use event callbacks of plugin to do what you need to. Assumes plugin has robust api for `events` interaction. A demo of what you have now would help

Comment: @ParrisVarney I have tried onclick '<button onClick="angular.element(this).scope().toggleModal('lcmdglytnbsb')">More detail</button>' however the modal no longer operates. are you saying to persist with that path? Hard is why i am here.

Comment: @charlietfl  Plugin ["Calendario: A Flexible Calendar Plugin"](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/27/calendario-a-flexible-calendar-plugin/). How would i know if the plugin handles api for events? (thanks for helping)

Comment: So within a directive , using the `onDayClick` callback you have access to both angular scope and event data ... hoe that helps. Note that events outside of angular that do anything with scope need to notify angular to run digest

Comment: Are you using a javascript loop that you could instead use ng-repeat with?  If so, angular would be able to use your ng-click attribute

Comment: @charlietfl Sounds good, i will persist with this and setup a demo when i get stuck.

Comment: @ParrisVarney what i find the problem with this is the calendar plugin requires the data source before angular... (that's the confusing "priority"  part)

Comment: @charlietfl After re reading your commenti should note that the html in the `span` tags has been added by me/php. the `onDayClick` was only returning calendar info which i didn't need so commented out.

Comment: @ParrisVarney how do i use ng-repeat within <script> tags to output the mentioned **data**

Comment: Not much we can do with limited amount of information given. Need to see some code and a demo

Comment: @charlietfl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147000/consuming-jquery-with-angularjs-ng-click-from-php-datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that jQuery should be loaded before angularJS in order to take precedence over jqLite:

> Real jQuery always takes precedence over jqLite, provided it was
>   loaded before DOMContentLoaded event fired.

Comment: Working with jquery and angular proved too tricky for a beginner like myself so i have abandoned using the jquery plugin for now.